# I can not send a broadcast action from the UI thread

Tags: android

From the Activity try send:

```
Intent bcIntent = new Intent();
bcIntent.setAction("ON_TICK");
this.core.context.sendBroadcast(bcIntent);
```

But does not works. MyBroadcast:

```
public class ServicesBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        // Log Action
        Log.d("app_log", "ServicesBroadcastReceiver action: " + action);
```

Have setting the manifest XML:

```
<receiver
            android:name=".services.ServicesBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":remote" >

            <intent-filter> ...
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please explain what "does not works" means, and please provide the complete `<receiver>` element (including the full `<intent-filter>`).

Comment: Full code: http://pastebin.com/WVFPKmw9 log does not shhow and does not call the functions after log, only filter works but from Activity does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an `Intent` with an action string of `"ON_TICK"`. You do not have an `<intent-filter>` in your manifest on that `BroadcastReceiver` with an action string of `"ON_TICK"`. Hence, your `BroadcastReceiver` will not receive this broadcast.

Comment: Good observation, implement and tell you if it works